# Flash Camera Permissions Dialog: Why does it sometimes take more than one click to work?

Tags: flash, actionscript

Often, but not always, the first few clicks on the "Allow" button on the Flash camera permissions dialog are ignored. This is very frustrating for users. And for me, when I'm testing code! I'm afraid I don't really know what else to say about the problem to give more insight. My hunch is that it has something to do with getting focus on the embed element, but that is merely a guess.

See Justin.tv for an example.